# Is this the correct behavior for SQL GET DIAGNOSTICS?

Tags: db2, ibm-midrange, db2-400, rpgle

The [documentation](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_ibm_i_73/db2/rbafzgetdiag.htm) for the SQL statement `GET DIAGNOSTICS` indicates that you can request that diagnostic data be placed in specific variables, with the relevant variable names and types listed.  The articles [here](https://www.rpgpgm.com/2017/03/using-get-diagnostic-for-sql-errors.html) and [here](https://www.mcpressonline.com/programming/sql/practical-sql-get-diagnostics) show how one can use this SQL statement in the context of an RPG program.

It looks like some of the results that I am getting back from DB2 do not match what the documentation and articles say.  I am on IBM i, version 7.3.

I am looking at the diagnostic data that is being returned from a SQL user-defined table function (UDTF).  If you use the clause "ALL" you can get a string that contains all the values:

```
COMMAND_FUNCTION=FETCH;
COMMAND_FUNCTION_CODE=+45;
DB2_NUMBER_CONNECTIONS=+1;
MORE=N;
NUMBER=+1;
CONDITION_NUMBER=+1;
DB2_MESSAGE_ID=SQL0443;
DB2_MESSAGE_ID1=CPF503E;
DB2_MODULE_DETECTING_ERROR=QSQFETCH;
DB2_ORDINAL_TOKEN_1=*N.*N;
DB2_ORDINAL_TOKEN_2=DUMMYUDTF;
DB2_ORDINAL_TOKEN_3=*******.DUMMYUDTF;
DB2_ORDINAL_TOKEN_4=Parameter '2' cannot be null.;
DB2_RETURNED_SQLCODE=-443;
DB2_TOKEN_COUNT=+4;
DB2_TOKEN_STRING=*N.*NDUMMYUDTFDUMMYUDTFParameter '2' cannot be null.;
MESSAGE_LENGTH=Parameter '2' cannot be null.;
MESSAGE_OCTET_LENGTH=Parameter '2' cannot be null.;
MESSAGE_TEXT=Parameter '2' cannot be null.;
RETURNED_SQLSTATE=90002;
ROUTINE_NAME=DUMMYUDTF;
ROUTINE_SCHEMA=QGPL;
SERVER_NAME=******;
SPECIFIC_NAME=DUMMYUDTF;
DB2_SQLERRD_SET=Y;
DB2_SQLERRD1=-168758331;
CONNECTION_NAME=******;
DB2_AUTHORIZATION_ID=********;
DB2_CONNECTION_METHOD=D;
DB2_CONNECTION_NUMBER=+1;
DB2_CONNECTION_STATE=+1;
DB2_CONNECTION_TYPE=+1;
DB2_PRODUCT_ID=QSQ07030;
DB2_SERVER_CLASS_NAME=DB2 for i;
DB2_SERVER_NAME=******;
```

The documentation states that fields `MESSAGE_LENGTH` and `MESSAGE_OCTET_LENGTH` should be integers.  As you can see they are both VARCHARs.  If I write code that defines these variables as integers, I get escape message: `Scalar operand does not have attributes required by instruction.` in the job log and two diagnostic, severity 50 `SQL system error.` along with a SQL service dump  `QSQSVCDMP`.  Another anomoly is that variable `DB2_MESSAGE_ID2` does not look like it is implemented and can make the program crash on the line where SQL assigns it.

In contrast, if I use `GET DIAGNOSTICS` on a built-in function, the data types all match what the documentation says and all the variables seem like they are available:

```
COMMAND_FUNCTION=SELECT;
COMMAND_FUNCTION_CODE=+65;
DB2_NUMBER_CONNECTIONS=+1;
MORE=N;
NUMBER=+1;
CLASS_ORIGIN=ISO9075;
CONDITION_NUMBER=+1;
DB2_MESSAGE_ID=SQL0138;
DB2_MESSAGE_ID1=CPF4278;
DB2_MESSAGE_ID2=CPD4317;
DB2_MODULE_DETECTING_ERROR=QSQOPEN;
DB2_ORDINAL_TOKEN_1=*N;
DB2_RETURNED_SQLCODE=-138;
DB2_TOKEN_COUNT=+1;
DB2_TOKEN_STRING=*N;
MESSAGE_LENGTH=+47;
MESSAGE_OCTET_LENGTH=+47;
MESSAGE_TEXT=Argument *N of substringing function not valid.;
RETURNED_SQLSTATE=22011;
ROUTINE_CATALOG=******;
SERVER_NAME=******;
SUBCLASS_ORIGIN=ISO9075;
DB2_SQLERRD_SET=Y;
DB2_SQLERRD1=-185403400;
DB2_SQLERRD2=-185339401;
CONNECTION_NAME=******;
DB2_AUTHORIZATION_ID=********;
DB2_CONNECTION_METHOD=D;
DB2_CONNECTION_NUMBER=+1;
DB2_CONNECTION_STATE=+1;
DB2_CONNECTION_TYPE=+1;
DB2_PRODUCT_ID=QSQ07030;
DB2_SERVER_CLASS_NAME=DB2 for i;
DB2_SERVER_NAME=******;
```

Is this a bug that should be reported to IBM?  How does one go about doing that?  I have made a UDTF and a calling RPGLE program to demonstrate the problem.  That code is below if anyone wants to verify my findings.  You will probably have to comment out a few lines in RPGLE program `TSTDIAUDTF` because you do not have my error message service program `ERRFUNC`.

`DUMMYUDTF` is an external user-defined SQL function with code in SQL and in RPGLE.  `TSTDIAUDTF` is an RPGLE program that I am using to test the behavior of the `GET DIAGNOSTICS` SQL statement.

This seems broadly similar to some bugs reported in the past, for instance [SI44066](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?mhq=get%20diagnostics&mhsrc=ibmsearch_a&uid=nas3SI44066), but the details are different.

**Edit:**
Corrected code formatting errors from earlier botched paste operation.

**DUMMYUDTF, TXT**

```
-- Build function by calling:
-- RUNSQLSTM SRCFILE(*******/QTXTSRC) SRCMBR(DUMMYUDTF) COMMIT(*NONE)

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION DummyUDTF( 
                             parm1    NUMERIC(7,0),
                             parm2    VARCHAR(7)
                             parm3    VARCHAR(4))
   RETURNS TABLE (Out1    NUMERIC(7,0),
                  Out2    VARCHAR(13),
                  Out3    VARCHAR(4),
                  Out4    NUMERIC(7,2), 
                  Out5    NUMERIC(5,4))
   LANGUAGE RPGLE 
   DETERMINISTIC 
   READS SQL DATA   
   CALLED ON NULL INPUT 
   DISALLOW PARALLEL 
   NOT FENCED
   EXTERNAL NAME '******/DUMMYUDTF'  
   PARAMETER STYLE DB2SQL;
```

**DUMMYUDTF, SQLRPGLE**

```
/IF DEFINED (*CRTBNDRPG)
H DFTACTGRP(*NO) ACTGRP('DUMMYUDTF')
/ENDIF
H DEBUG
H ALWNULL(*USRCTL) OPTION(*NoDebugIO) EXTBININT(*YES)

D DUMMYUDTF       PI

*  Input Parameters
D parm1                          7S 0
D parm2                          7A   VARYING
D parm3                          4A   VARYING

* Columns to be returned
D out1                           7S 0
D out2                          13A   VARYING
D out3                           4A   VARYING
D out4                           7S 2
D out5                           5S 4

* NULL Indicators for all input and output parameters
D parm1_n                        5I 0
D parm2_n                        5I 0
D parm3_n                        5I 0

D out1_n                         5I 0
D out2_n                         5I 0
D out3_n                         5I 0
D out4_n                         5I 0
D out5_n                         5I 0

* SQL Function Parameters

D OutputSQLState                 5A
D FunctionName                 517A   VARYING CONST
D SpecificName                 128A   VARYING CONST
D MessageText                 1000A   VARYING
D CallType                      10I 0


* Locals

D CallTypeFirst   C                   CONST(-2)
D CallTypeOpen    C                   CONST(-1)
D CallTypeFetch   C                   CONST(0)
D CallTypeClose   C                   CONST(1)
D CallTypeFinal   C                   CONST(2)

D out             DS                  TEMPLATE QUALIFIED
D  out1                          7S 0
D  out2                         13A   VARYING
D  out3                          4A   VARYING
D  out4                          7S 2
D  out5                          5S 4

D results         DS                  DIM(99) LIKEDS(out)
D index           S              2S 0
D count           S              2S 0

D var4            S              7S 2
D var5            S              5S 4

MONITOR;

OutputSQLState = *ZEROS;       // Initialize Output Parameters
CLEAR MessageText;

SELECT;
WHEN CallType = CallTypeOpen;
IF parm1_n = -1;
MessageText = BuildNullError('1');
RETURN;
ENDIF;
IF parm2_n = -1;
MessageText = BuildNullError('2');
RETURN;
ENDIF;
IF parm3_n = -1;
MessageText = BuildNullError('3');
RETURN;
ENDIF;
IF parm1 < 1;
OutputSQLState = '90002';
MessageText = 'Parameter 1 must be a number greater than 0.';
RETURN;
ENDIF;
EXSR BuildDummyData;

WHEN CallType = CallTypeFetch;
index += 1;
IF index > count;
OutputSQLState = '02000';
RETURN;
ENDIF;

out1 = results(index).out1;
out2 = results(index).out2;
out3 = results(index).out3;
out4 = results(index).out4;
out5 = results(index).out5;
WHEN CallType = CallTypeClose;
*INLR = *ON;
ENDSL;
ON-ERROR;
DUMP;  // This dump ends up in the output queue QUSRSYS\QEZDEBUG
OutputSQLState = '90001';
MessageText = 'Error occurred in RPG program ''DUMMYUDTF''. ' +
'See program dump for additional details.';
ENDMON;
RETURN;

********************************************************************
BEGSR BuildDummyData;

EXEC SQL SELECT 350.05, .65
INTO :var4, :var5
FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1;

SaveToResults(parm1 : parm2 : parm3 : var4 : var5);
SaveToResults(219 : 'ABCDEF'     : 'ZYXW' : 20.1 : .65);
SaveToResults(438 : 'GHIJKLMNOP' : 'ZYXW' : 2.95 : 0);
ENDSR;

********************************************************************

P BuildNullError...
P                 B
D                 PI          1000A   VARYING
D  parmName                     20A   VALUE VARYING

OutputSQLState = '90002';
RETURN 'Parameter ''' + parmName + ''' cannot be null.';
P                 E

********************************************************************

P SaveToResults...
P                 B
D                 PI
D  loc1                          7S 0 VALUE
D  loc2                         13A   VALUE VARYING
D  loc3                          4A   VALUE VARYING
D  loc4                          7S 2 VALUE
D  loc5                          5S 4 VALUE

IF count = 99;
OutputSQLState = '10Z01';
MessageText = 'SQL warning in DUMMYUDTF +
More than 99 parts generated.';
ELSE;
count += 1;
results(count).out1 = loc1;
results(count).out2 = loc2;
results(count).out3 = loc3;
results(count).out4 = loc4;
results(count).out5 = loc5;
ENDIF;
P                 E
```

**TSTDIAUDTF, SQLRPGLE**

```
H DEBUG(*YES)
H MAIN(Main)
H DFTACTGRP(*NO)
H BNDDIR('ERRFUNC')

/copy QRPGLESRC,ERRFUNCPR
D  Message        DS                  LIKEDS(ErrorMsg)

D success         S              3I 0
D failure         S              3I 0
D diagAll         S          32740A   VARYING
D displayText     S             52A

D dummyItem       DS                  INZ
D  out1                          7S 0
D  out2                         13A
D  out3                          4A
D  out4                          7S 2
D  out5                          5S 4

D SQLDiagData     DS                  INZ
D  MessageID                    10A
D  MessageID1                    7A
D  MessageID2                    7A
D  MessageLength                 5I 0
D  MessageText               32740A   VARYING
D  otherType                 32740A   VARYING
D  ReturnedSQLCode...
D                                5A
D  ReturnedSQLState...
D                                5A
D  RowCount                     10I 0

P Main            B

DSPLY 'Beginning of test';
TestDummyUDTF();
TestDiagnoticsFromUDTF();
TestDiagnoticsFromBIF();

DSPLY ('Successful tests: ' + %char(success));
DSPLY ('Failed tests:     ' + %char(failure));
RETURN;

BEGSR *PSSR;
DUMP;
DSPLY 'Unexpected error while running tests.';
GetErrorMsg(Message);
DSPLY ('Message.MsgId: ' + Message.MsgId);
DSPLY (%subst(Message.MsgText:1:52));
RETURN;
ENDSR;
P                 E

********************************************************************

P TestDiagnoticsFromBIF...
P                 B

D text            S             10A
DSPLY 'Causing error from SUBSTR to read diagnostics.';
EXEC SQL SELECT SUBSTR('ABC', 1, -1) INTO :text
FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1;
IF SQLSTATE = '00000';
failure +=1;
DSPLY 'Test failed. Data returned, no error.';
ELSEIF SQLSTATE = '02000';
failure +=1;
DSPLY 'Test failed. No error returned.';
ELSE;
ReadSQLDiagnosticsAll();
IF diagAll <> '';
success += 1;
DisplayTextWindow(diagAll : 'CPF9898':'QCPFMSG');
DSPLY 'GET DIAGNOSTICS ALL succeeded.';
ELSE;
failure +=1;
DSPLY 'GET DIAGNOSTICS ALL failed.';
ENDIF;

ReadSQLDiagnosticsAllCondition();
IF diagAll <> '';
success += 1;
DisplayTextWindow(diagAll : 'CPF9898':'QCPFMSG');
DSPLY 'GET DIAGNOSTICS ALL CONDITION succeeded.';
ELSE;
failure +=1;
DSPLY 'GET DIAGNOSTICS ALL CONDITION failed.';
ENDIF;

ReadSQLDiagnostics();
IF ReturnedSQLCode <> '-138 ' OR
ReturnedSQLState <> '22011';
failure +=1;
DSPLY 'Test failed. Unexpected diagnostic.';
displayText = 'SQLCODE  ' + ReturnedSQLCode +
'   SQLSTATE ' + ReturnedSQLState;
DSPLY displayText;
ELSE;
displayText = MessageText;
DSPLY displayText;
displayText = 'MESSAGE_LENGTH ' + %char(MessageLength);
DSPLY displayText;
displayText = 'DB2_MESSAGE_ID  ' + MessageID +
' DB2_MESSAGE_ID1 ' + MessageID1;
DSPLY displayText;
displayText = 'DB2_MESSAGE_ID2 ' + MessageID2;
DSPLY displayText;
IF MessageText <> '';
success += 1;
DSPLY 'GET DIAGNOSTICS MessageText succeeded.';
ELSE;
failure +=1;
DSPLY 'GET DIAGNOSTICS MessageText failed.';
ENDIF;
ENDIF;
ENDIF;
P                 E

********************************************************************

P TestDiagnoticsFromUDTF...
P                 B

D var2            S              7A
D var2_n          S              5I 0

var2_n = -1;
DSPLY 'Causing error from DummyUDTF to read diagnostics.';
EXEC SQL DECLARE CUR_DIAG_UDTF CURSOR FOR (
SELECT ITEMS.*
FROM TABLE (QGPL.DummyUDTF(22, :var2 :var2_n, 'ZZ')) AS ITEMS
);
EXEC SQL OPEN CUR_DIAG_UDTF;
DOW 1=1;
EXEC SQL FETCH CUR_DIAG_UDTF INTO :dummyItem;
IF SQLSTATE = '00000';
failure +=1;
DSPLY 'Test failed. Records returned, no error.';
LEAVE;
ELSEIF SQLSTATE = '02000';
failure +=1;
DSPLY 'Test failed. No error returned.';
LEAVE;
ELSE;
ReadSQLDiagnosticsAll();
IF diagAll <> '';
success += 1;
DisplayTextWindow(diagAll : 'CPF9898':'QCPFMSG');
DSPLY 'GET DIAGNOSTICS ALL succeeded.';
ELSE;
failure +=1;
DSPLY 'GET DIAGNOSTICS ALL failed.';
ENDIF;

ReadSQLDiagnosticsAllCondition();
IF diagAll <> '';
success += 1;
DisplayTextWindow(diagAll : 'CPF9898':'QCPFMSG');
DSPLY 'GET DIAGNOSTICS ALL CONDITION succeeded.';
ELSE;
failure +=1;
DSPLY 'GET DIAGNOSTICS ALL CONDITION failed.';
ENDIF;

ReadSQLDiagnosticsUDTF();
IF ReturnedSQLCode <> '-443 ' OR
ReturnedSQLState <> '90002';
failure +=1;
DSPLY 'Test failed. Unexpected diagnostic.';
displayText = 'SQLCODE  ' + ReturnedSQLCode +
'   SQLSTATE ' + ReturnedSQLState;
DSPLY displayText;
ELSE;
*        DSPLY MessageID;
*        DSPLY %char(MessageLength);
displayText = MessageText;
DSPLY displayText;
displayText = 'MESSAGE_LENGTH ' + OtherType;
DSPLY displayText;
displayText = 'DB2_MESSAGE_ID  ' + MessageID +
' DB2_MESSAGE_ID1 ' + MessageID1;
DSPLY displayText;
IF MessageText <> '';
success += 1;
DSPLY 'GET DIAGNOSTICS MessageText succeeded.';
ELSE;
failure +=1;
DSPLY 'GET DIAGNOSTICS MessageText failed.';
ENDIF;
ENDIF;
LEAVE;
ENDIF;
ENDDO;
EXEC SQL CLOSE CUR_DIAG_UDTF;
P                 E
********************************************************************

P TestDummyUDTF...
P                 B

D expected        DS                  DIM(3) LIKEDS(dummyItem)
D index           S              3I 0

expected(1).out1 = 22;
expected(1).out2 = 'AAAA';
expected(1).out3 = 'ZZ';
expected(1).out4 = 350.05;
expected(1).out5 = .65;
expected(2).out1 = 219;
expected(2).out2 = 'ABCDEF';
expected(2).out3 = 'ZYXW';
expected(2).out4 = 20.1;
expected(2).out5 = .65;
expected(3).out1 = 438;
expected(3).out2 = 'GHIJKLMNOP';
expected(3).out3 = 'ZYXW';
expected(3).out4 = 2.95;
expected(3).out5 = 0;

DSPLY 'Running test on DummyUDTF, success expected.';
EXEC SQL DECLARE CUR_UDTF CURSOR FOR (
SELECT ITEMS.*
FROM TABLE (QGPL.DummyUDTF(22, 'AAAA', 'ZZ')) AS ITEMS
);
EXEC SQL OPEN CUR_UDTF;
DOW 1=1;
EXEC SQL FETCH CUR_UDTF INTO :dummyItem;
IF SQLSTATE = '00000';
index += 1;
IF out1 <> expected(index).out1 OR
out2 <> expected(index).out2 OR
out3 <> expected(index).out3 OR
out4 <> expected(index).out4 OR
out5 <> expected(index).out5;
failure +=1;
DSPLY 'Test failed. Data mismatch from UDTF.';
ELSE;
success += 1;
DSPLY 'Test succeeded.';
ENDIF;
LEAVE;
ELSEIF SQLSTATE = '02000';
IF index = 0;
failure +=1;
DSPLY 'Test failed. No records returned.';
ENDIF;
LEAVE;
ELSE;
failure +=1;
DSPLY ('Test failed. SQLSTATE ' + SQLSTATE);
// ReadSQLDiagnostics();
LEAVE;
ENDIF;
ENDDO;
EXEC SQL CLOSE CUR_UDTF;
RETURN;
P                 E

**************************************************************************

P ReadSQLDiagnostics...
P                 B
D                 PI
D  condition#                    5I 0 VALUE OPTIONS(*NOPASS)

IF %parms = 0 OR condition# < 1;
condition# = 1;
ENDIF;
EXEC SQL GET DIAGNOSTICS CONDITION :condition#
:SQLDiagData.ReturnedSQLCode  = DB2_RETURNED_SQLCODE,
:SQLDiagData.ReturnedSQLState = RETURNED_SQLSTATE,
:SQLDiagData.MessageText      = MESSAGE_TEXT,
:SQLDiagData.MessageLength    = MESSAGE_LENGTH,
:SQLDiagData.MessageID        = DB2_MESSAGE_ID,
:SQLDiagData.MessageID1       = DB2_MESSAGE_ID1,
:SQLDiagData.MessageID2       = DB2_MESSAGE_ID2;
RETURN;
P                 E

**************************************************************************

P ReadSQLDiagnosticsUDTF...
P                 B
D                 PI
D  condition#                    5I 0 VALUE OPTIONS(*NOPASS)

IF %parms = 0 OR condition# < 1;
condition# = 1;
ENDIF;
EXEC SQL GET DIAGNOSTICS CONDITION :condition#
:SQLDiagData.ReturnedSQLCode  = DB2_RETURNED_SQLCODE,
:SQLDiagData.ReturnedSQLState = RETURNED_SQLSTATE,
:SQLDiagData.MessageText      = MESSAGE_TEXT,
:SQLDiagData.otherType        = MESSAGE_LENGTH,
:SQLDiagData.MessageID        = DB2_MESSAGE_ID,
:SQLDiagData.MessageID1       = DB2_MESSAGE_ID1;

//   :SQLDiagData.MessageLength    = MESSAGE_LENGTH,
//   :SQLDiagData.MessageID        = DB2_MESSAGE_ID;

RETURN;
P                 E

************************4*************************************************

P ReadSQLDiagnosticsAll...
P                 B

EXEC SQL GET DIAGNOSTICS :diagAll = ALL;
RETURN;
P                 E
**************************************************************************

P ReadSQLDiagnosticsAllCondition...
P                 B
D                 PI
D  condition#                    5I 0 VALUE OPTIONS(*NOPASS)

IF %parms = 0 OR condition# < 1;
condition# = 1;
ENDIF;
EXEC SQL GET DIAGNOSTICS :diagAll = ALL CONDITION;
RETURN;
P                 E

P DisplayTextWindow...
P                 B                   Export
D                 PI
D Text                        8192    Const Varying
D MessageId                      7    Const
D MessageFile                   21    Const

D ErrCode         DS
D  BytesIn                      10I 0 INZ(0)
D  BytesOut                     10I 0 INZ(0)

DQUILNGTX         PR                  EXTPGM('QUILNGTX')
D MsgText                     8192    CONST
D MsgLength                     10I 0 CONST
D MessageId                      7    CONST
D MessageFile                   21    CONST
D dsErrCode                           LIKE(ErrCode)

QUILNGTX(Text : %Len(Text) :
MessageId : MessageFile : ErrCode);
P                 E
```

Answer (score 3):

Yeah, it looks like it could be a bug...or given the PTF you linked to...it could be a limitation of `GET DIAGNOSTICS` when working with external UDTFs.

I see the same thing on 7.2.

What PTF level's are you at?  If not current, IBM will ask you to get current.

You can report the issue here: https://www-946.ibm.com/support/servicerequest/Home.action

IBM will likely ask for code to reproduce.  You'll probably want to cut down your example to the bare minimum to reproduce.  Actually, it's s good idea to do so beofre posting to stackoverflow the next time.

As an example, here's all that's needed when calling the UDTF to see the problem:

```
**free
ctl-opt actgrp(*NEW) main(mainline) cvtopt(*NOVARCHAR) debug(*yes);
dcl-pr mainline extpgm('TESTRPGLE');
end-pr;


dcl-proc mainline;

  dcl-s diagAll varchar(32740);
  dcl-ds dummyItem qualified;
    out1 zoned(7);
    out2 varchar(13);
    out3 varchar(4);
    out4 zoned(7:2);
    out5 zoned(5:4);
  end-ds;
  dcl-s nullArr int(5) dim(5);

  exec sql
    declare C1 cursor for (
    SELECT ITEMS.*
     FROM TABLE (DummyUDTF(22, cast(null as varchar(7)), 'ZZ')) AS ITEMS
     );

  exec sql
    open C1;

  //I expected  SQLSTATE to be 90002 here, but it's not
  if sqlstate <> *ZEROS;
    exec sql
      get diagnostics :diagAll = ALL;
    dump;
    return;
  endif;

  exec sql
    fetch C1 into :dummyItem :nullArr;

  //here's where the SQLSTATE of 90002 is returned.
  if sqlstate <> *ZEROS;
    exec sql
      get diagnostics :diagAll = ALL;
    dump;
    return;
  endif;
  return;
end-proc;
```

**side note: start using fully free format ;)**